# PowerBI - Split Column By List of Delimeters

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery, m

New to M/PowerQuery here.

I have a column of filenames and I am trying to extract the files based upon a "short filename" which is only the name of the file with the extension stripped. The issue I have is that many of the files contain multiple extensions as well as periods in the short filenames as well.

For example: I want "1.5 in screw.ipt.dwg" and create a column that is **just ** "1.5 in screw". Any other new columns that are blank or contain the extensions are irrelevant and I can ignore them.

My solution was to generate a column that was just file extensions (which worked), then tell PowerBI to strip any strings found within from the column of file names. If I manually told PowerBI to strip a specific extension by giving it a literal string, that worked great: it would remove the extension from the string and generate a series of blank columns that I am free to ignore.

However, I want to know if, instead of a literal string, I can give PowerBI a column or list of strings to check and split by all of them.

I am basically a newbie when it comes to Power Query/M, so I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm hoping to not have to resort to a secondary data table generated with a SQL query, but that's my current fallback if this doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Nicholas

EDIT: For confidentiality purposes, I sadly cannot include real examples of the data I am working with.

Comment: Please supply a minimal reproducible example in copiable text format and your expected results.

Comment: Yes, you can use a list. And your "confidentiality" argument does not explain why you cannot make the effort to generate a list that replicates your problem by using made up data.

Comment: I am eternally baffled by this.  I've seen increasing numbers of people ask a question but refuse to provide any way to solve the issue because of confidentiality.

Comment: @horseyride My guess is they don't think about how to create sample data and lay that burden on those responding. I am also disturbed by the people who provide sample data as screenshots, rather than as text that can be easily copy/pasted..

Answer (score 1):

In M you can use the `Splitter` function.

If you are adding a column and using the GUI, something like:

```
= Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter({".ipt",".dwg"})([File Name]){0}
```

for the custom column formula.

will return your desired result from your example.

And you can replace `{".ipt",".dwg"}` with a list of file extensions.